# adb pull file in Arabic Language(UTF-8) encoding

Tags: batch-file, cmd, adb

i tried to pull it using

```
adb pull /sdcard/جهات الإتصال.vcf D:/
```

but when i write it in CMD it's shows as non-understood language 
any ideas please

Comment: PowerShell has better handling of Unicode characters.  If you prefer to stick with cmd, then try `chcp 65001` to change the console codepage to Unicode.  Either way, you'll also probably need a console font that contains glyphs for Arabic characters.  It appears that [DejaVu Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21753872/1683264) would probably work.  But then you might have to reverse the file name to reference it, since Arabic is a right-to-left language.  I foresee some trial and error in your future.

Comment: Thanks
i tried through PowerShell and CMD i change font and reverse the words,the cmd now understand Arabic but when i apply adb pull command it's returned to non-understood lanugage and the same error like this(C:\Users\Dell>adb pull /sdcard/لاصتإلا تاهج.vcf D:\
remote object '/sdcard/ط????ط?' does not exist)

Comment: There is a blank space in the Arabic string; try to enclose the file name in a pair of double quotes as follows: `adb pull "/sdcard/جهات الإتصال.vcf" D:/`. Try with `chcp 1256` or `chcp 720` as well.

Comment: thanks man here is what i got..
i tried your methods but it says that the file not exist
and what i've done is i ran adb shell
`cd sdcard  `
'ls'
and copy the file name in non-understood lanugage (ط¬ظ‡ط§طھ ط§ظ„ط§طھطµط§ظ„.vcf) 
then i run 'adb pull "sdcard/ط¬ظ‡ط§طھ ط§ظ„ط§طھطµط§ظ„.vcf" "D:/جهات الاتصال.vcf" ' with 'chcp 1256' 
note that the dir is in " " 
and it works temporarily 
is there any way to convert this(/ط¬ظ‡ط§طھ ط§ظ„ط§طھطµط§ظ„.vcf) to an understood words ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question has deleted answer by @sachin-das stating that `adb.exe` from andriod platform tools handles Japanese filenames properly.

I've rechecked that `platform-tools-latest-windows.zip\platform-tools\adb.exe` version 1.0.39 from [Andriod Platform Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) handles Russian filenames correctly too.

My old `adb.exe` v1.0.32 was corrupting filenames. While `adb.exe` of the same v1.0.32 from @sachin-das's google drive didn't.

So I guess there are different builds of adb of the same version roaming in the wild.